# How can I make this Python filterwarnings statement work?

Tags: python

I'm in the process of upgrading a large Django project to the latest version of that framework.  To help identify things that will soon be deprecated, I've begun running my unit tests with Python's -W argument:

```
python -Wa manage.py test classes.tests.test_file.TestFileClassIT.test_copy_all_files
```

When I run a test in this manner I get a lot of errors like this:

```
/srv/https/example.com/repo/classes/tests/test_file.py:30: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name='/var/www/example.com/photos/file.txt' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

I would like Python to ignore all warnings of this type as I don't have time to go in and fix this in the hundreds of tests that triggers it.  To do that, I discovered that the warnings package provides this capability so I've added it to one of the test modules to understand how it works:

```
# test_file.py
import unittest

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message="ResourceWarning: unclosed file*")

class TestFileClassIT(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_copy_all_files(self):
        ...
        open("file1.txt", "w").close
        ...
```

However, I am still seeing the ResourceWarning in the output from my tests.  I've read the documentation and this appears to be how to use the warnings module.  I've also tried my warning without including the asterisk and the end of the warning string but that doesn't work either.  What is the proper way to include this warning in my code so that it works properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On that **specific** error, *inside your test function* `test_copy_all_files` in your class `TestFileClassIT`

```
    warnings.simplefilter('ignore', ResourceWarning)
```

On all errors, have you tried with inserting a *simple* entry into the list of warnings instead of `filterwarnings`?

```
    warnings.simplefilter('ignore')
```

According to PEP-0565 on [warnings system](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0565/#other-documentation-updates)

```
    if not sys.warnoptions:
        warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
```